# How do you tame an Ocelot in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have found an Ocelot in Minecraft, but I cannot tame it. When I try, the Ocelot gives off hearts, but does not become tamed.

Answer (score 1):

From Minecraft Explorer:

> **How to tame an Ocelot**:
>
> 1. Hold a Raw Fish whilst standing perfectly still and not looking around too quickly.
> 2. The Ocelot will slowly approach the player. When the Ocelot is close enough, use the Raw Fish on the Ocelot to tame it. (See notes below.)
> 3. Once the Raw Fish has been used, the Ocelot will turn into one of three different cat types.
>
> **Important**
>
> Ocelots can only be tamed when they walk to the player on their own.

Comment: While pictures can certainly answer a question, pictures of text help not at all.  They're not searcheable, nor do they contribute to SEO.  It'd also be a good idea to link to where you got this from.

Comment: I did I put "from Minecraft explorer"

Comment: Okay.  So what site is that?  Link it!  That will help with attribution.

Comment: It's the smartphone app Minecraft explorer